# Entity Framework - LINQ selection in POCO generic List property

Tags: linq, entity-framework, generics, collections

I'm having some issues setting a generic list property of a POCO object when from an EF context. For instance I have a very simple object that contains the following:

```
 public class foo
 {
    public string fullName;
    public Entity entity;
    public List<SalesEvent> eventList;
 }
```

My code to populate this object from looks something like this:

```
  .Select(x => new foo()
                {
                    fullName = x.vchFirstName + " " + x.vchLastName,
                    entity = new EntityVo()
                    {
                        address1 = x.vchAddress1,
                        entityId = x.iEntityId,
                        emailAddress = x.vchEmailAddress,
                        firstName = x.vchFirstName,
                        lastName = x.vchLastName,
                        city = x.vchCity,
                        state = x.chState,
                        workNumber = x.vchWorkNumber,
                        mobileNumber = x.vchMobileNumber,
                        siteId = x.iSiteId

                    }
                    eventList = _context.Events
                              .Where(e => e.iEntityId == x.iEntityId
                                        && e.iStatusId >= eventStatusMin
                                        && e.iStatusId <= eventStatusMax)
                              .Select(e => new List<SalesEventMatchVo>
                                           {
                                               new SalesEventMatchVo()
                                                   {
                                                     vehicleName = _context.Quotes.Select(q=>q).Where(q=>q.iEventId == e.iEventId).FirstOrDefault().vchMake + " " + _context.Quotes.Select(q=>q).Where(q=>q.iEventId == e.iEventId).FirstOrDefault().vchModel,
                                                     eventId =  e.iEventId,
                                                     salesPerson = e.chAssignedTo,
                                                     eventStatusDesc=_context.RefDefinitions.Select(r=>r).Where(r=>r.iParameterId==e.iStatusId).FirstOrDefault().vchParameterDesc,
                                                     eventStatusId =(int)e.iStatusId,
                                                     eventSourceDesc=_context.RefDefinitions.Select(r=>r).Where(r=>r.iParameterId==e.iSourceId).FirstOrDefault().vchParameterDesc,
                                                    createDate = e.dtInsertDate

                                                   }
                                           }).FirstOrDefault()
                }).ToArray();
```

This issue I'm having is that I'm unable to populate the eventList property with all of the events, it's only grabbing the first record(which makes sense looking at the code). I just cant seem to figure out to populate a the entire list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason simply removing the `FirstOrDefault` at the end isn't the solution here? I feel like I might be misunderstanding something.

EDIT:

I think I see what you are trying to do. The issue is that you are creating a list in the select statement, when the select statement works only over one thing at a time. It is basically mapping an input type to a new output type.

Try something like this instead:

```
eventList = _context.Events.Where(e => e.iEntityId == x.iEntityId &&     //FILTER EVENTS
                                       e.iStatusId >= eventStatusMin &&
                                       e.iStatusId <= eventStatusMax)
                           .Select(e => new SalesEventMatchVo()          //MAP TO SALESEVENT
                                        {
                                             vehicleName = _context.Quotes.Select(q=>q).Where(q=>q.iEventId == e.iEventId).FirstOrDefault().vchMake + " " + _context.Quotes.Select(q=>q).Where(q=>q.iEventId == e.iEventId).FirstOrDefault().vchModel,
                                             eventId =  e.iEventId,
                                             salesPerson = e.chAssignedTo,
                                             eventStatusDesc=_context.RefDefinitions.Select(r=>r).Where(r=>r.iParameterId==e.iStatusId).FirstOrDefault().vchParameterDesc,
                                             eventStatusId =(int)e.iStatusId,
                                             eventSourceDesc=_context.RefDefinitions.Select(r=>r).Where(r=>r.iParameterId==e.iSourceId).FirstOrDefault().vchParameterDesc,
                                             createDate = e.dtInsertDate
                                         })
                           .ToList() //CONVERT TO LIST
```

As a side note, unless you actually need a `List` for some reason, I would store `foo.eventList` as `IEnumerable<SalesEvent>` instead. This allows you to skip the `List` conversion at the end, and in some scenarios enables neat tricks like delayed and/or partial execution.

Also, I'm not sure what the point of your `.Select(q=>q)` statements are in several lines of the `SalesEventMatchVo` initializer, but I'm pretty sure you can chop them out. If nothing else, you should `Select` after `Where`, as `Where` can reduce the work performed by all following statements.